# RabbitMQ - Regex Implementation Topic Exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

Suppose, If I have a binding key as "a.b.*" then I can use the routing keys as a.b.1, a.b.2, a.b.3 , a.b.4 and so on.

I want the queue to accept messages from the all these routing keys **except** the  routing key **"a.b.3"**. How can that be implemented?

Or is there any way I can use **regex** for my binding key instead of just the wildcard characters "*" and "#".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No; there's no regex, just the two wildcards.

You can use multiple bindings though - you would have to explicitly bind the queue with a.b.1, a.b.3, a.b.4, but then, you might as well just use a direct exchange.

Comment: in addition to what Gary said, there is not "except" or "not" or "exclude" in routing / binding with rabbitmq. a match is a match and will always route the message.